# Calculate the minimum value of an integer $x$, such that $\left\lfloor\frac{xy^2}{xy+w(y-z)}\right\rfloor>z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, diophantine-equations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given integers:

- $y>z>0$
- $w>0$

I want to calculate the minimum value of an integer $x$, such that $\left\lfloor\frac{xy^2}{xy+w(y-z)}\right\rfloor>z$.

I've figured that I can instead solve $xy^2=(xy+w(y-z))(z+1)$.

The solution I got is $x=\frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)}{y^2-yz-y}+1$.

However, when I put it on a quick test, it fails for:

- $y=3$
- $z=1$
- $w=3$

As $x=\frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)}{y^2-yz-y}+1=5$ solves $\left\lfloor\frac{xy^2}{xy+w(y-z)}\right\rfloor>z$, but $x=4$ also solves it.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How did you get from solving $xy^2=(xy+w(y-z))(z+1)$ to $x=\frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)}{y^2-yz-y)}+1$? More specifically, where does the +1 come from?

Comment: @mode_er: The "+1" comes in order to get rid of the "floor" in the original equation.

Comment: I don't think I understand. How does adding one to x get rid of the floor function? I got a similar answer and posted it below, but there was no plus one. Your second answer looks more promising but in that case, x isn't always an integer ($w=1,z=2,y=4$ as a counterexample)

Comment: @mode_er: You're right. I meant to use floor on that answer (i.e., integer division).

Comment: @mode_er: And BTW, $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor+1=\left\lceil\frac{n}{k}\right\rceil$. So your answer is essentially identical to mine, and it also includes a proper logical inference, so I will mark it green. Tx!

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb "of an integer x", do you need to exclude the case $x < 0$?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Also, if $w = 1, y = 3, z = 1$, then $x = \lfloor \frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)}{y^2-yz-y}\rfloor = 1$ where $\frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)}{y^2-yz-y} = 4/3$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy^2=(xy+w(y-z))(z+1)$$

$$xy^2-xy*(z+1)=w(y-z))(z+1)$$

$$xy(y-z-1)=w(y-z))(z+1)$$

$$x=\left \lceil\frac{w(y-z)(z+1)}{y^2-zy-y}\right\rceil$$

Since we need x to be an integer, we simply round up

EDIT: If you don't want to round up, simply find $a$ when

$$w(y-z)(z+1)+a\text{ mod } {y^2-zy-y} \equiv 0$$ and the solution becomes
$$x=\frac{w(y-z)(z+1)+a}{y^2-zy-y}$$

Comment: Because $\left\lceil\frac{n}{k}\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor+1$, your answer is essentially identical to mine, and it includes a proper logical inference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it seems that the correct solution is $x=\frac{w(yz-z^2+y-z)\color\red{-1}}{y^2-yz-y}+1$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).